# Combine varied number of dynamically named arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have seen the following: [array_merge() How can I add a 'range' of an array name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067698/array-merge-how-can-i-add-a-range-of-an-array-name) and the answers don't work for me.

I have an array that I am looping through in order to slice and convert certain currency strings to float numbers. I then have to array_merge them back together in order to work with the array and have been dynamically naming them so that I don't overwrite the previous array_merge. After doing so, I then need to combine all of the dynamically named arrays into one array.

Initially I had the following code, which worked great when I only had 3 nested arrays in the $order['product'] array. However, this number varies, and the code needs to do so as well.

```
$nr = 1;
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
    $product_total = array_slice($product, 1);
    array_walk($product_total, "convertCurrencyStringtoNumber");
    ${"final_product" . $nr} = array_merge($product, $product_total);
    $nr++;
}; 
$arrays = array($final_product1, $final_product2, $final_product3);
var_dump($arrays);
```

This results in the following array:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
    ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
    ["total"]=> float(18) } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
    ["total"]=> float(17) } 
[2]=> array(2) { 
    ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
    ["total"]=> float(2.75) } }
```

**How do I implement a varied number of dynamically named arrays in the line:**

```
$arrays = array($final_product1, $final_product2, $final_product3);
```

I attempted the following, but the array is nested incorrectly. Feel free to fix this code or come up with a better solution.

```
$nr = 1;
$i = 1;
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
    $product_total = array_slice($product, 1);
    array_walk($product_total, "convertCurrencyStringtoNumber");
    ${"final_product" . $nr} = array_merge($product, $product_total);
    if ($nr > 0) {
        $arrays = $final_product1;
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $nr; $i++) {
            $arrays = array_merge($arrays, ${"final_product" . $nr});
        }
        } else {
            echo "There are no products in this order";
        }
$nr++;
}; 
var_dump($arrays);
```

This results in the incorrectly nested array:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
        ["total"]=> float(18) } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
        ["total"]=> float(17) } } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" 
    ["total"]=> float(2.75) } }
```

Comment: Why not simply generate a new array instead of single dynamically-named variables?

Comment: that's just.. painful. varvars always end up kicking you in the privates. Why can't you do **ONE** array, and use your dynamic names as the primary key? `$arr[$dynamic_key] = ... stuff here...`?

Comment: I am painfully teaching myself php and could not think of a better way in my limited knowledge. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace your dynamically single-named variables with an array:

```
$final_product = array();
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
    $product_total = array_slice($product, 1);
    array_walk($product_total, "convertCurrencyStringtoNumber");
    $final_product[] = array_merge($product, $product_total);
}; 
var_dump($final_product);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here... this should be as easy and simple as:

```
$final_array=[];
foreach ($order['product'] as $product) {
 $final_array[]['total'] = (float) $product['whatever value 1 is...'];
 $final_array[]['source_code'] = $product['source_code'];
}
var_dump($final_array);
```

If you need to apply `convertCurrencyStringtoNumber`because it does something weird to the variable then changethe seccond line to:

```
$final_array[]['total'] = convertCurrencyStringtoNumber(array_slice($product, 1));
```

Comment: I accepted another answer as this code separated every element into its own index: array(6) { 
 [0]=> array(1) { 
  ["total"]=> float(0) } 
 [1]=> array(1) { 
  ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" } 
 [2]=> array(1) { 
  ["total"]=> float(0) } 
 [3]=> array(1) { 
  ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" } 
 [4]=> array(1) { 
  ["total"]=> float(0) } 
 [5]=> array(1) { 
  ["source_code"]=> string(10) "408000-025" } }